# Which cellphone provider offers cheap internet in Perú?

Tags: cellphones, internet, peru, mobile-operators

Which cellphone provider offers cheapest internet in Perú.

Cheap in price, good data volume, flat rate as possible.

Answer (score 1):

Because I think it's not really well known I started the question just to answer it myself.

Right now it seems to be Bitel.
They're service is not yet spreaded like Movistar or Claro, but they're developing.
So they're the first we came across with a flat rate like we're used to from Germany. Bitel got different pre-payed plans.

1 day flat
1 month flat with different volumes

So, after finishing the volume they just limiting the speed, so you got still internet access.

Tethering works quite nice for us. Check out they're [plans](http://www.bitel.com.pe/new-detail-service/paquetes/paquete-mimax.html)

And no, I'm not affiliated in any way. Just like to share knowledge.

Comment: While you're at it, how do they compare to the other providers?

Comment: They don't have prepaid flatrates at all. So they limit volume and at least Claro is even limiting the time. For example you get 50mb for 3 days. Movistar seems to be similar with the limitation, the packages are almost the same. Just to clarify, I'm talking about prepaid, I don't know the other plans, but contracts have flatrates as far as I know.